# Python Tuple last row and last column

Tags: python

I have a tuple of rows and columns and wanted to access the last row and last column from it.

how to do this?

Comment: Can you give some code that you have tried?

Comment: I suggest that you learn about the `len()` function.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I suggest he learns about **indexing** in general, and **indexing** in python. As you can iterate with negative numbers for reverse purpose in python, he could, instead of using `len()` (that would iterate through all the list) use `-1` that would take the first char, in reverse (the last one). (Maybe that using negative numbers go through the `len()` function, but I'm unsure about this)

Comment: @IMCoins Good point. I forgot about this feature of Python.

Comment: Indexing and slicing explained here, on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/8881141

Answer (score 2):

If you have one dimensional tuple, let's say `t`, you can do `t[-1]` to get the last element.

Or if your tuple has 2 dimensions, you can use `t[-1][-1]` to get the last row and last column. For example:

```
>>> my_tuple = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> my_tuple[-1][-1]
6
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Always explain your answers clearly and it's always good to explain the result with the help of example. That way you'll get better response to your answer. Take a look at my edit for reference. :)

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer,. I'm new to StackOverflow, so I'm not very good at type a format answer, but I will try to do it next time.